# Configure EI analytics with Cassandra DB

Tags: wso2, esb

How to configure EI analytics with cassandra database in WSO2?

I want to display all my Cassandra table in EI Analytics - DataExplorer.

Referred the below link but unable to proceed.

Link: https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Configuring+Data+Persistence+With+Cassandra

Comment: So You mean  EI  Analytics does not support Cassandra?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Seems I'm wrong. What is the error that you get?

Comment: so once i am doing the setup mentioned in the above link,i am getting the below error

Comment: [2017-08-01 16:57:32,430] [EI-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.AnalyticsTask} -  Error while executing the scheduled task for the script: EsbAnalytics-SparkScript-Realtime-Statistic
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.exception.AnalyticsExecutionException: Exception in executing query CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE